# rails_admin gets stuck during generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRkqR.png)

The rails_admin gem gets stuck during `rails g rails_admin:installation`

After giving me the option to press enter the cursor moves to the next line with no further generation.

It gets stuck here:

```
$rails g rails_admin:install 
< To mount rails_admin? Press for[admin]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting spring?

`spring stop ; rails g rails_admin:install`

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2239

Answer (score 0):

For me, `spring stop` didn't fix this. I had to set the DISABLE_SPRING environment variable on the command line to get the installation to do anything:

```bash
export DISABLE_SPRING=1
rails g rails_admin:install
```

I was upgrading rails_admin from a 2.0 version to a 3.0 version.